# AWS Error: 'production' database is not configured

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services

I trying to deploy my app on AWS with remote mysql server but I have this error when I trying to Oper rails c or do rake db. This is nginx error:

```
App 14089 output: Error: The application encountered the following error: 'production' database is not configured. Available: ["prodcution"] (ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified)
```

Also I tried to looking for in google, but articles like this doesn't help me.
[Production database is not configured](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20351976/production-database-is-not-configured)

My database.yml:

```
prodcution:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: "mydb"
  username: "mydbuser"
  password: "mydbpassword"
  port: 3306
  host: "mydb.amazon.rds.amazonaws.com"
```

What I do wrong?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your database.yml file has a typo `prodcution`, shouldn't it be `production`.

Comment: Oh nope, thank you. what a stupid mistake

Comment: who doesnt make mistakes :) no big deal

Comment: @BorisKuzevanov Please accept the answer if it answered your question.